# is Activiti 5.9 BPM Production ready?

Tags: activiti

We are evaluating BPM 2 product for our production system. We are looking at Activiti 5.9 as an alternative to jBPM 5.x. Not sure if Activiti 5.9  is production ready. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used Siganvio open source for the modeler and Activiti for our engine. We did not use the Activiti web-app since we found it buggy, but it is nice for testing. Activiti has some limitations but overall the API is straightforward and easy to master, the community helps a lot, and there is decent documentation. I suggest "Activiti in action" as a great starting point. See my [blog](http://developer4life.blogspot.co.il/2012/02/activiti-authentication-and-identity.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with

> production ready

If you look for a professional solution I may suggest using camunda fox [here](http://www.camunda.com/fox/product/overview/)

Activiti offers a lot - but with the support is not so easy.